# How to generate API_KEY and API_SECRET of Dropbox in android application

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am using [Dropbox SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs) for implementing Dropbox to the android application, I done the silent login, file uploading.. I am doing these with the help of four parameters Username, password, api key and api secret. Now I want to perform this without inserting api key and api secret, means i want to generate api key and api secret in my android application.

I tried a lot for this, but cannot find any help.
Is there any possibility to generate API_KEY and API_SECRET dynamically?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the names of those variables, it looks like you will not be able to generate them yourself.  Their purpose is for the Dropbox guys to control who can use their API: they make a key for each user, revoke it if the user's being naughty, or let you use more/faster if you pay them more.  Think of it as another layer of login, and you'll see why it doesn't make sense for you to generate them yourself.

Edit: I'll make it clearer.  No, you can't.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but is there any way to generate API Key and Secret?